# Could not resolve host android.googleapis.com (Google Cloud Messaging)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push, host, resolve

I'm trying to send a PUSH notification to my users and I'm getting an "GCM error: Could not resolve host: android.googleapis.com" error. 
I'm doing it from PHP using Curl, and I must say that this was working two days ago. 
Anyone is having the same issue? Do you know what is going on?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I have read that it might be a DNS issue. Try `# nslookup android.googleapis.com` then `#dig A android.googleapis.com`. Also check resolvers config file **/etc/resolve.conf** and add dns server ip in resolve.conf.

Comment: If just using http, I've been using this: `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send`

Comment: It was a DNS issue from my ISP as @abielita said. Thank you both